# How repeat this curl request in C#?

Tags: c#, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

This CURL request i need make in C#

```
 curl  --noproxy site.local -v --key ./client.key --cert ./client.crt --cacert ./client-trusted.crt https://site.local:9000/index.html
```

I have this C# code

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate X509certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors) { return true; };

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;            
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://site.local:9000/ssl-secured");

string certificateText = File.ReadAllText("C:\\client.crt");
string privateKeyText = File.ReadAllText("C:\\client.key");
ICertificateProvider provider = new CertificateFromFileProvider(certificateText, privateKeyText);
X509Certificate2 certificate = provider.Certificate;
request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And i get exception

> System.Net.WebException: 'The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.'

In CURL this request work fine. How make this curl request in C# ?

Comment: Not sure if this could be the (or a) reason: You are setting `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` twice. So the second setting should overwrite the first. Is that intentional?

Comment: ^^ Nevermind. Both settings will result in the same enum value. Are you sure the target can handle TLS 1.2 ? The curl does not seem to enforce v1.2 of TLS?

Comment: yes i should handle TLS v1.2

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Have you tried 1.1 and 1.0 ?

Comment: I not have variants 1.1 or 1.0. Just TLS 1.2

Comment: try this ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: you can also try making ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback return true (bad practise but ok for diagnosing an error like this)

Comment: It does not help

Comment: I dont know what else to suggest except calling certificate.Verify() and seeing if that provides useful info